# Problema "AAPT2" Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema en android con el error

> "AAPT2 error: check logs for details"

Ya vi tutoriales y muchos recomiendan que ponga `android.enableAapt2=false` en el archivo `gradle.properties`, pero me sale otro error

> "The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used
>   anymore. Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
>
> It will be removed at the end of 2018..".

Luego me sale otro error que es

> "Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\GONZALO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1".

Y hasta ahí el problema, ¿qué debería hacer?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tuve ese error y el problema era que estaba implementando una librería que no debía, allí lo que te dice es que el AAPT2 esta deprecado, es decir que ya no se usa, que cambies su valor a true para quitar ese alerta i/o problema, igual esta opción sera removida a finales del 2018, y el error de abajo (la ultima pantalla), no se muestra completo, te recomiendo que edites la publicación para que se pueda ver el error completo.

Comment: Te sugiero revises en Help > Show Log in Explorer y verifiques que error se muestra. En realidad este error puede deberse a múltiples causas. @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal

Comment: Hola @DavidVillegas , en la 3er imagen vendría a ser este el error "Process 'command 'C:\Users\GONZALO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal , aquí (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value) hablan acerca de ese error, parece que va ligado a alguna característica de `graddle` que te esta dando error, también dan posibles soluciones, intenta probarlas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te recomiendo es que lo pongas en false en tu `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

También haz lo siguiente, ir a:

> settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run

Y desactiva todos los check como te muestro en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Depués haz clean y make project